# Angular 4 Router Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular2-routing

So I'm trying to unit test with Jasmine, first time ever doing it. I've read that you must create mocks. I've done so, however -- as soon as I provide the mock for RouterStub, I get the error "cannot read root of undefined"

```
class RouterStub {
navigate(params){

}
```

}

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ FpUserIdComponent ],
  imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpModule, 
       TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
          deps: [ Http ]
  }
})
  ],
  providers: [
      ForgotPasswordService, CorrelateID, ErrorToggleService, ApiService,
    { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
    { provide: ActivatedRouteStub, useClass: ActivatedRouteStub },
    { provide: "api.config", useFactory: getData },
    { provide: Router, useValue: RouterStub }
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

}));

My Component:

```
export class FPUserIdComponent implements OnInit, ComponentCanDeactive {
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private forgotpasswordservice: ForgotPasswordService,
private errorToggleService: ErrorToggleService,
private apiService: ApiService ) { }

}
```

Comment: This might help you if you didn't already solve it: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/